# Get image id from image created via remote API

Tags: docker

I'm using the Docker Remote API (API v1.6, Docker 0.6.5). I'm building an image via the POST /build endpoint. FWIW, my client is written in Go. Is there a way to get the image ID of the image I just created without having to parse it out of the streamed response text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give it a name (e.g. *repo:tag*) during the build and then inspect information about the tagged image using `GET /images/(tag name)/json`. ([docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/master/api/docker_remote_api_v1.6/#get--images-%28name%29-json))

The json information includes the id, as well as the "config" which shows how the image was created in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I ended up tagging the image and using that tag name as the image for the container. That way I was able to avoid the interstitial step of requesting the image.